# in app billing: How to find expiration date of user subscription

Tags: android, android-billing

I am adding a subscription feature to my app. Is there any way I can know the expiry date of the current subscription?

I searched everywhere and  cant seem to find the answer

Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the expiration date for subscriptions is only available through the Google Play Android Develop HTTP-based API. You can always calculate the expiration date using the`AIDL` for subscriptions. If you request `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS` (assuming you have no previous local data) you'll get the purchase date and the current state of the the subscription and a couple of other data.

Comment: Ah I see. If I query purchases, I will get the purchase date  as part of the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA, right?

Comment: Thanks you accepted! I posted another question on SO , maybe you know the answer

Comment: I have posted an answer for that question as well.. Please check